# c# Parallel foreach with Lambda Expression to filter files

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\DataArchiver\KYEC\", "*.stdf.gz", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                .Select(x => new FileInfo(x)).Where(x.length > 100000)
                ,file =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file);
            });
```

**I am having an error:** Error 2   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' has some invalid arguments    C:\MteProjects\ThreadPool\ThreadPool\Program.cs 70  21  ThreadPool

After adding .where(x.length > 100kb) i

Answer (score 1):

You missed x=> in where clause:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\DataArchiver\KYEC\", "*.stdf.gz", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                .Select(x => new FileInfo(x)).Where(x => x.length > 100000)
                ,file =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file);
            });
```